# Importing CSV into SQL server via Sql Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server

When importing into SQL using CSV import via Import and Export Wizard, I am recieving error: : "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PKxxx', table 'XXXX.dbo.tblXXX'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

When importing, I am actually selecting to ignore this column as it is the primary key, I just want to rest of the import to run and match up with the primary key in terms of the existing table.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: If the column is defined in the table and you choose to not insert anything into it, you are by definition trying to insert null values when you add new rows.  If the column is a PK, this will obviously cause issues.

Comment: You say you want to *"match up with the primary key in terms of the existing table"*, but what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert unique value in to the field which is your primary key.
other wise it will give you error because you are inserting the value in the data base.
in csv file in place of primary key insert the unique values and import hope this will help